# How to activate iptables after connecting to VPN?

Tags: vpn, iptables

I want to block all non-vpn traffic, for which I have a script with iptables rules that works fine. The problem is that I can only set those rules *after* being connected to the vpn (if I do it before, I can't connect to the vpn). The connection to the vpn happens when I login, because that's how the network manager works (each user can handle its own connections).

So how do I auto-execute a script as root, after I'm logged in and connected to the vpn? I might need this even for non sudoer users

Comment: Which VPN? How is the VPN managed?

Comment: @mgorven I'm using openvpn and network-manager (nmcli). I think I will have to use a C binary with setuid to activate/deactivate iptables on startup. Not sure how to wait for the non-vpn connection to be ready though.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need iptables, but just change the default gateway. for openvpn, you can use "redirect-gateway def1" on client side, or push .... on the server side.
if the above doesn't meet your need, you can also use "up" scripts in your openvpn config file.

```
script-security 2
up /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: I need iptables to make sure that there is no way out of my pc, other than the vpn tunnel. If I don't do this, something can go wrong and my real ip will be revealed, or data may be sent in cleartext.